# Do we need a tag [agn] or is [active-galaxy] enough?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

I was a bit suprised that [agn](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agn) did not exist, and neither does [active-galactic-nucleus](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/active-galactic-nucleus), and I just created it because [a search showed 72 results](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=agn) (as of 2021-04-15). On second thought, it is probably a good idea to ask here, what the community thinks about these tags, and in particular how big the overlap to [active-galaxy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/active-galaxy) is, before I start adding [agn](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agn)-tags to older questions.

IMHO [active-galaxy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/active-galaxy) contains a [agn](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agn), but a question about a [agn](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agn) is not necessarily about a complete [active-galaxy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/active-galaxy).

Now, that we are at it, should we also create [active-galactic-nucleus](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/active-galactic-nucleus) and make it a synonym of [agn](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agn)?

Comment: It would be better if we make them synonyms. There is no need to having a tag that is pretty much the same as another.

Comment: [tag:active-galaxy] only has 21 questions. If all the AGN questions had that tag it would actually be on its way to having enough usage to be community moderated. I don't see a good reason to fragment it.

Comment: @called2voyage So please consider my question a synonym-request then :-)

Comment: @B--rian Ok, done! Merged and synonymized [tag:agn] --> [tag:active-galaxy] and created the synonym [tag:active-galactic-nucleus] --> [tag:active-galaxy].